# How to call WCF Service from Android application via WiFi Network?

Tags: android, wcf, wifi

I have WCF Service and my Android application consumes it. I am doing this with emulator and WCF Service running on the same machine. Now I am running WCF Service on WiFi enabled Laptop and installed Android application on WiFi enabled Mobile. I want to access WCF Service via WiFi network.
Please give me guide line to do this.
Do I need to have Wireless Router?
What are the process/Settings that I need to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the ip address of your server (WCF Service) on your WiFi network and put it in the url of your android app.

Comment: Do I need to have Wireless Router?

Comment: I guess you already have a router if your server and android device are connected to WiFi.

Comment: "I am doing this with emulator and WCF Service running on the same machine"

Comment: Actually the emulator has its own ip address, so you can't refer to the server in the android app as 127.0.0.1. Find your ip on your network with ipconfig in command line and set it as the server part server of your url in your android app.